# No element found for selector: in (Puppeteer Error)

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

This is the code I have given:

```
const puppeteer=require('puppeteer');
var username="123";
var password="222";

(async()=>{
    const browser=await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});

    const page=await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://kds-net.obic7.obicnet.ne.jp/ZADMbl/MainFrame.aspx', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
    await   page.type('#txtKyoushuuseiNO',username);
    await   page.type('#txtPassword',password);
    await   page.waitForNavigation();
})();
```

I'm getting an error where I showed in the code. I checked the location and the location seems correct. Where could I have gone wrong??

Error is here:
Error: No element found for selector: #txtKyoushuuseiNO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your elements are inside an iframe, which needs to be selected, then queried within:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^21.6.0

const url = "<Your URL>";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: "new"});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const f = await page.waitForSelector("#frameMenu");
  const frame = await f.contentFrame();
  await frame.type("#txtKyoushuuseiNO", "123");
  await frame.type("#txtPassword", "222");
  await page.screenshot({path: "test.png"});
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Remarks:

- In the output screenshot, you'll see the username has '0000' prepended. This is added automatically by the site when the input field is blurred. If you enter a long enough username, it won't be added. I assume '123' is just a placeholder.
- [Prefer 'domcontentloaded' to 'networkidle0'](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#never-using-domcontentloaded).
- [Generally avoid `page.waitForNavigation();`](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/02/08/puppeteer-in-nodejs-common-mistakes-to-avoid.html#making-unnecessary-calls-to-waitfornetworkidle-or-waitfornavigation), except when you're clicking on something that triggers navigation (and make sure to set the navigation listener before the click).

<sub>Disclosure: I'm the author of the blog posts linked above.</sub>